# Refering css link in .css file

Tags: css, angular

I want to refer the bootstrap link (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)in .css file.

Please let me know how to refer this in angular project

Answer (score 0):

Try import the link at the top of your css file:

```
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your CSS file (ideally *styles.css* of your Angular project):

```
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```